# create table and insert failure using pandas sqldf

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to create a new table using pandas sqldf as shown below:

```
pip install -U pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf
sqldf("create table mytable (id integer, name text)")
sqldf("select * from mytable")
```

This is failing showing

```
OperationalError: no such table: mytable
```

My goal is to insert data into the table as shown below:

```
sqldf("insert into mytable values (1, 'abc')");
sqldf("insert into mytable values (2, 'def')");
sqldf("insert into mytable values (3, 'ghk')");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This can be solved using sqlite3; but if anyone has a better and easy solution, please let me know.

Comment: to create a table you need some kind of dtabase, sqlite is one of then panda works mostly with dataframes as they are tables you can run queries on it, so may you are only searching for dataframes